# Pandas hiding a column, to stay in df, but not displayed in html table

Tags: python, pandas

I have +-300 lines of code to give me a specific df table.. this table needs to be displayed in html. Everything is set up and working perfectly. The only problem is, that I have a column within the df (that is crucial for other big calculations) that I cannot delete or adjust. I would like to keep this column within in the df, but want to hide it when viewing html table

For example (simplified):

```
'''The table I have as df (cannot be changed fundamentally) '''
    col1 col2 col3 col4
r1  2   34   45   23
r2  2   65   34   56
r3  2   34   34   54
r4  2   76   54   34

'''The Table I need to be displayed in html (without actually removing col1, just hiding it)'''
    col2 col3 col4
r1  34   45   23
r2  65   34   56
r3  34   34   54
r4  76   54   34
```

Comment: why dont you simply save the dataframes in two different variables?

Comment: Or why not just use `print(df.drop('col1', axis=1))` which doesn't actually drop it from `df1`, just returns a changed copy for printing

Comment: Just select columns you want to print with another variable and print it. `df_print = df[['col2', 'col3', 'col4']]`

Comment: Thanx, df.drop does get the df to 'hide' col1, but the problem is when I want to use col1 for the next calculation, all of col1 values become = 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create custom css styles. Here are added borders and hidden column `col0` by [`Styler.set_table_styles`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.set_table_styles.html):

```
css = [
{
       'props': [
           ('border-collapse', 'collapse')]
},       
{
       'selector': 'th',
       'props': [
           ('border-color', 'black'),
           ('border-style ', 'solid'),
           ('border-width','1px')]
},
{ 
       'selector': 'td',
       'props': [
           ('border-color', 'black'),
           ('border-style ', 'solid'),
           ('border-width','1px')]
},
{'selector': '.col0', 
 'props': [('display', 'none')]}]

html = df.style.set_table_styles(css).render()
```

EDIT:

If want printing DataFrame without `col1` then is possible use [`DataFrame.drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) this column or select only columns for printing:

```
df_print = df.drop('col1', axis=1)
df_print = df[['col2', 'col3', 'col4']]
```

Comment: should I add this before 'df_html = DataFrame(df)"? or after?

Comment: @LlewellynHattingh - output is `html`, sorry, wrong variable

Comment: @petezurich - Thank you

Comment: thanx all, I went with @talatccan answer.. for simplicity sake.. I appreciate all answers

Comment: @LlewellynHattingh - Yes, added to answer.