# Shape error when trying to color a cell of dataframe and then dump it as html and trying to retain style for cell

Tags: python, html, pandas, styles

I have a csv file which contains 6 columns for multiple rows. In my case ideally values in c3 should match with value of c5 and c4 with c6. If not the one that is lesser the text in that cell should be highlighted with red.

```
C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6
a,b,21,200,21,200
c,d,1050,1900,1050,1900
k,l,250,1300,250,1330
j,m,230,1400,228,1339
s,t,210,1900,220,1900
```

Now i read this file using panda.read_csv and convert to html file using .to_html function. But ideally i should also color  C4 column with value 1300 as red since it is less than C6 value of 1330 in row3. Similarly color 228 and 1339 as C5 and C6 are less than C3 and C4 respectively for row4.

what i tried to do is basically first read_csv to a pandas dataframe, and then use df.style.apply(fnToColorRed,axis=1) and inside fnToColorRed i tried to color it but it does not work.

```
def fnToColorRed(value):
    color= red if ( value['C2'] != value['C4'] or value['C3'] != value['C5'] ) else black
    return 'color %s ' %color

csv_file_df=pd.read_csv("my.csv")
style=csv_file_df.style.apply(fnToColorRed,axis=1)
df_html=style.render() 
df_html.to_html('my.html')
```

But above does not seem to work. In fact i get below error on line: df_html=style.render() which is function returned the wrong shape. ValueError: Function fnToColorRed returned the wrong shape. Result has shape:(5,) Expected shape: (5,6).

Note that i want that html file that is created has the cell color retained as red if it satisfies criteria `color= red if ( value['C2'] != value['C4'] or value['C3'] != value['C5'] ) else black` as mentioned in code above.

Thanks

Comment: there should be a way to do it in python with 13 views still no hint from anyone is a surprise to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create DataFrame of styles by custom function with compare columns with set them in [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) first and pass to [`Styler.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html), last for write to file use `file.write` function:

```
def fnToColorRed(x):
    c1 = 'color: red'
    c2 = 'color: black' 

    # condition
    m = x[['C3','C4']].to_numpy() != x[['C5','C6']].to_numpy()
    #print (m)
    #empty DataFrame of styles
    df1 = pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
    #set new columns by condition
    df1[['C3','C4']] = np.where(m, c1, c2)
    df1[['C5','C6']] = np.where(m, c1, c2)
    return df1
```

Then is possible specify some css:

```
css = [
{
       'props': [
           ('border-collapse', 'collapse')]
},       
{
       'selector': 'th',
       'props': [
           ('border-color', 'black'),
           ('border-style ', 'solid'),
           ('border-width','1px')]
},
{ 
       'selector': 'td',
       'props': [
           ('border-color', 'black'),
           ('border-style ', 'solid'),
           ('border-width','1px')]
}]
```

---

```
style=df.style.apply(fnToColorRed, axis=None).set_table_styles(css)

with open("my.html", "w") as file:
    file.write(style.render())
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate this a little. I tried to print(m) and x inside fnToColorRed but do not get ouput in anaconda. Though this solution works very close to what i want. I see by using to write html file using with open instead of to_html provided by pandas the border between column disappears giving a clumsy look if two column with lesser width are there, numbers appears close to each other.

Comment: `Though this solution works very close to what i want` - If need check in anaconda need `anaconda notebook`. How looks expected ouput if need something else?

Comment: I got that m creates a 2 columns and check if C3!=C5 and C4!=C6 and assign true or false to that matrix. You then created an empty dataframe and and then returned the styler where column C3,C4,C5,C6 gets assigned color: black or color: red and then it gets applied to dataframe "df" . Am i correct ? How can i put borders similar to provided by to_html() from pandas using in the styler ? Thanks

Comment: @Invictus - You  are absolutely correct. For borders is necessary add some custom css, it is possible, but need some time.

Comment: thanks can you please help with that ? Or guide me to some resource related to it.

Comment: Looks like column C1 disappear or collapse and is not visible after applying the css.

Comment: @Invictus - yop, need remove `,
    {'selector': '.col0', 
     'props': [('display', 'none')]}`

Comment: @Invictus - I forget remove it from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59711861/2901002) solution (there was requirement remove it)

Answer (score 1):

It's expecting you to return the full row of colors if you are using axis=1.  So try:

```
def fnToColorRed(value):
    color0 = 'black'
    color1 = 'black'
    color2 = 'red' if value['C3'] < value['C5'] else 'black'
    color3 = 'red' if value['C4'] < value['C6'] else 'black'
    color4 = 'red' if value['C5'] < value['C3'] else 'black'
    color5 = 'red' if value['C6'] < value['C4'] else 'black'
    return ['color %s ' % color0, 'color %s ' % color1, 'color %s ' % color2, 'color %s ' % color3, 'color %s ' % color4, 'color %s ' % color5]
```